# What does it means the security parameter K for cryptographic signatures schemes

Tags: signature

Cryptographic schemes claim to use a security parameter K for deriving signing key and verification key. What does this parameter signify ? how can be chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *security parameter* (usually denoted $k,\lambda$ or $\kappa$) is the input to the algorithms of a cryptosystem against which we measure security. That is it should have no effect on correctness of the scheme but only its security against attacks.

*Formally* the only requirement for this parameter is that attacks grow in time super-polynomial in this parameter and the time for legitimate applications of the scheme grows polynomially in this parameter.

*Practically* one also often encounters security parameters to make comparisons between parameter sets across schemes. For example a 384-bit elliptic curve has 192-bit security, AES-192 has 192-bit security and 3072-bit RSA has 128 bit security. So if you are asked for a security parameter independent of the scheme it usually is the "x-bit security" parameter, but when asked for a concrete scheme it usually is the "x-bit $Scheme" parameter. For all practical purposes a general security level / parameter of 128-bit is sufficient.

Comment: What about functional signatures security parameter ?

Comment: @E.Emy there the security parameter _may_ have an influcene ont he sizes of the operands for the function, but in general its main responsibility is as in the answer (and unless you name a specific scheme it should be a case of "general security")